# Creating composer package for Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am trying to create my first composer package for **Codeigniter 4**. However, I always get an error `Class 'Myapp\Settings\Greet' not found`. I'm totally lost.

I created a folder inside the **ThirdParty** folder named **myapp-settings**. Inside of that folder is another folder called **src** and `composer.json`.

Here's the content of that `composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "myapp/settings",
    "description": ".",
    "license": "MIT",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Myapp\\Settings\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "require": {}
}
```

I created a test file inside the **src** folder named `Greet.php`

```
<?php namespace Myapp\Settings;

class Greet
{
    public function hello()
    {
        return 'Hey, there!';
    }
}
```

On codeigniter's `App\Config\Autoload.php`

```
public $psr4 = [
    'Myapp\Settings' => APPPATH . 'ThirdParty/myapp-settings/src'
];
```

Then on codeigniter's default controller I called it.

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

use Myapp\Settings\Greet;

class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $h = new Greet();
        echo $h->hello();
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

Once I run it I got an error `Class 'Myapp\Settings\Greet' not found`. `APPPATH\Controllers\Home.php at line 9`. How can I fix this?

Comment: DId you not fire `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: I did but still the same error\

Comment: Not really versed with Codeigniter, but does it have it's own composer.json?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of editing the codeigniter's `app/Config/Autoload.php`, revert it and add these lines to the project `composer.json`:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "app/ThirdParty/myapp-settings"
    }
],
// "require": {
```

Then run `composer require myapp/settings`

Since I have also stuck at this problem, a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mondayrris/ci4-create-package) is created just for it. You might check and clone, watch the commits to understand the steps.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me in my issue to get a package running locally.